Import dash_bootstrap_components doesn’t work
Issue:  I pip3.8 installed dash_bootstrap_components and Import dash_bootstrap_components doesn’t work.  How can  I fix my error  ?
this is what I have:
 # Creates the interactive dashboard using the dash library

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import dash

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from dash_table import DataTable

from dash import dcc

from dash import html



import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from PIL import Image

#import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

#from plotly.colors import qualitative



import plotly.graph_objects as go 

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/marlainna456/corona/dashboard.py", line 11, in <module>

    import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_bootstrap_components'

pip3.8 install --user dash_bootstrap_components
also tried importing dash_bootstrap_components as dbc.
in PythonAnywhere

You've installed the package with pip3.8 -- are you sure you're using Python 3.8 to run the code?  How are you running it?

#!/usr/bin/python3.8
pip3.8 isntall --user dash_bootstrap_components

Could you clarify what you mean by that?  The first part appears to be a hashbang, and the rest a command.

This error indicates that Python cannot find the dash_bootstrap_components package. You can try the following steps to resolve the issue:
1. Verify That the Package Is Installed:
In your terminal, run the following command to check if the dash_bootstrap_components package is installed:
pip3.8 show dash-bootstrap-components

If the package is not installed, you can install it using:
pip3.8 install dash-bootstrap-components

2. Ensure You’re Using the Correct Python Interpreter:
If you have multiple versions of Python installed, ensure that the Python interpreter you're using to run your script is the same one where the package was installed.
You can check the path of the Python interpreter with:
which python3.8

Then, verify that the package is installed for that specific interpreter by running:
python3.8 -m pip show dash-bootstrap-components

3. Check If You’re Using a Virtual Environment:
If you are using a virtual environment, make sure it’s activated before running your script. After activating the virtual environment, try installing the package and running your script again:
source /path/to/your/venv/bin/activate  # Unix/MacOS
.\path\to\your\venv\Scripts\activate  # Windows

With the virtual environment active, install the package using pip3.8 install dash-bootstrap-components and then try running your script again.
4. Reconfirm Your Pip and Python Version:
If the above steps don’t resolve the issue, make sure that the pip version corresponds to the correct Python version:
python3.8 -m pip install dash-bootstrap-components

These steps should help resolve the issue. If the problem persists, feel free to provide more details, and I can assist you further.
